# Indoor map for a private building

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary

I am trying to create an application to show an indoor map of a building, and open the dialog box when anyone clicks on any part of that building. It's similar to IndoorGoogle Maps 6.0 for Android, but Indoor maps are currently available in selected locations in the U.S. and Japan only.

I don't know whether I should use a WebView (because it has scrolling and zoom features) or an ImageView. How to show a marker in the image of the map like Google Maps? How should I save the direction from one part to another part of the building?

Comment: I am also trying the same thing...if you get it then let me also know.

Comment: Similar stackoverflow discussion [here][1].

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358715/how-to-build-a-mall-map-for-android

Comment: Dear @Nibha Jain, did you got the solution? If yes, could you please to share. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Nibha : have you got solution . I am working for the same? How we can put custom markers on this?

Answer (score 8):

ImageView can probably get you a quick-and-dirty version, but WebView would probably be better. Check out the [mapping API from Micello](http://www.micello.com/products/javascriptAPI), and [this Google I/O talk](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/map-your-business-inside-and-out.html) on indoor mapping using the Google Maps API.

A few other reference apps to look at: [PointInside](http://www.pointinside.com), [Aisle411](http://aisle411.com/), [Meridian](http://www.meridianapps.com/).

My startup, BuildingLayer, does [some indoor map stuff](http://api.buildinglayer.com/blfm/view/building/91/floor/12#) as well. We use [Leaflet](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/) out front, which is buttery smooth on iOS's Mobile Safari, but you lose pinch-zoom capabilities in the stock Android browser (looks like this issue is being resolved with Mobile Chrome & Android ICS).

Comment: Links are dead and post is pretty outdated

Comment: Yep, I was the answerer here, startup is dead now, that server is gone. Leaflet.js project is still alive, just has a new home: http://leafletjs.com/ Even 3.5 years later, indoor mapping hasn't made much progress. Indoor positioning is a really tough challenge (GPS doesn't work inside, no viable alternative right now), don't expect much adoption until that's further along.