# Can one program a custom map view with custom map (eg map of floor of a mall, office) in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to build a mall map for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358715/how-to-build-a-mall-map-for-android)

Can one program a custom map view with custom map (eg map of floor of a mall, office) in android ?

How do we do it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this using the standard toolset that Android supply you (MapView and the whole Google Maps package).

There are a few commercial thirdy-party solutions out there. Google for indoor positioning or indoor navigation.

As an alternative, you could adapt one of the open source map viewers and navigation systems that have been developed so far. Have a look at openstreetmap, for example:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Main_Page

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Software/Mobile

Comment: Thanks for the info. But it still doesn't serves the purpose as i am unable to set my custom map as view in it. Maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Do you mean setting a custom map (an image) in a Google MapView? I think that this cannot be done at all. Google Maps is intended to be used with the maps published by Google *only* (AFAIK). You *can* show a custom map (a JPG/PNG image) in an Android ImageView (see docu) but from this point on, you will be alone. No ready-to-use maps services at all on custom maps. As an alternative, you could create a map *layer* on a Google Map (a collection of Point-of-Interests, a GPS track and things like that). Have a look at the Google Maps docu for this.