# Can anyone help me how to create a map for a building?

Tags: android

Does anyone know how to create a 2D building map for example a mall, and also locate or pinpoint the user current location? My classmate told me to use Google Maps API, but I prefer not to use it.

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12358715/1127492

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've a friend that swears by OpenStreetMap so if you don't want to follow the Google route then this could be a good option. They too are interested in creating maps for indoor space and lots of information can be found here:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/IndoorOSM

I'm no expert, but by the looks of it, it seems as if there are tools, such as [JOSM](http://josm.openstreetmap.de/), which allow you to create the indoor maps - a quick start guide to using JOSM indoors can be found [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/IndoorOSM#Mapping_data_in_JOSM). It does seem to assume that you have floor plans of a building. As far as I'm aware (correct me if I am wrong) there is currently no software, that lets you walk around a building creating a map!

Locating a users current location is difficult. GPS tends not to work in indoor spaces, so you need to consider which would be the best option. Additionally if you are working with a multi-floored building then you need some method to work out what floor the user is on. There are a number of possible solutions:

- Attach GPS Antennae to the buildig and use a repeater to boost the coverage to the rest of the building
- Google [uses](http://www.smh.com.au/digital-life/smartphone-apps/inside-out-google-launches-indoor-maps-20130312-2fxz2.html) wi-fi networks and mobile masts to determine location. If you want to know more about this approach check out WifiSlam. They're now owned by Apple but there are some interesting articles in the top 10 or so search results of Google about them and this technology!
- Use image recognition to determine the users location. You could use something like Google Goggles. Users could take images of the room-numbers/shop-signs/QR codes which are then processed followed by a location being provided

None of these are particularly easy, so perhaps a different approach could be taken!