# How to build offline office building maps?

Tags: android, .net, maps

We are planning to do a offline map of an office building, the maps should be able to navigate anyone to a desired points like Cafe, Printers, Restroom, breakout area, helpdesk etc. I am new to this and not sure what technology to be used for this, Can someone help me with the right technology to develop this in .Net.
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: you can use openstreetmap for offline map. here is lib https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look into [osmdroid](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid) it´s a library that allows you to do exactly what you want using map from [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/).

We are using it to have features like in "Google Map" but being offline with images loaded on an SDCard. You can use tools like [Mobac](http://mobac.sourceforge.net/) to create the offline atlases.

I'm just not sure if you will be able to add overlays to the map...

Comment: is this for creating Indoor maps? like inside a building to locate different points

Comment: can you please visit this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358715/how-to-build-a-mall-map-for-android